# How to update record in listview as well as Database in android

Tags: java, android, database, listview, android-arrayadapter

I want all edit text content that I have saved in SQL to be displayed on the edit bills activity when I click on the list item, but I am only able to retrieve the name and display it again in the intent. Rather than saving another data it should update the record with the new data if I save the existing record another time in the editbills_activity. Here is my DBAdapter.java

```
package com.example.dhruv.bills;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log; 
public class DBAdapter {
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_AMOUNT = "amount";
public static final String KEY_DUEDATE = "duedate";
private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "billsdb";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "bills";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;



private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table if not exists assignments (id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + "name VARCHAR not null, amount VARCHAR, duedate date );";

// Replaces DATABASE_CREATE using the one source definition
private static final String TABLE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + // AUTOINCREMENT NOT REQD
                KEY_NAME + " DATE NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_AMOUNT + " VARCHAR ," +
                KEY_DUEDATE + " DATE " +
                ")";

private final Context context;

private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
{
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE); // NO need to encapsulate in try clause
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts"); //????????
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

//---opens the database---
public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException
{
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

//---closes the database---
public void close()
{
    DBHelper.close();
}

//---insert a record into the database---
public long insertRecord(String name, String amount, String duedate)
{
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    initialValues.put(KEY_AMOUNT, amount);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DUEDATE, duedate);
    //return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    // Will return NULL POINTER EXCEPTION as db isn't set
    // Replaces commented out line
    return DBHelper.getWritableDatabase().insert(DATABASE_TABLE,
            null,
            initialValues
    );
}

//---deletes a particular record---
public boolean deleteContact(long rowId)
{
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

//---retrieves all the records--- SEE FOLLOWING METHOD
public Cursor getAllRecords()
{SQLiteDatabase db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String query ="SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE;
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    return data;
}


//As per getAllRecords but using query convenience method
public Cursor getAllAsCursor() {
    return DBHelper.getWritableDatabase().query(
            DATABASE_TABLE,
            null,null,null,null,null,null
    );
}
public void deleteName(int id, String name){
    SQLiteDatabase db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "DELETE FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE "
            + KEY_ROWID + " = '" + id + "'" +
            " AND " + KEY_NAME + " = '" + name + "'";
    Log.d(TAG, "deleteName: query: " + query);
    Log.d(TAG, "deleteName: Deleting " + name + " from database.");
    db.execSQL(query);
}
public Cursor getItemID(String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT " + KEY_ROWID + " FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE +
            " WHERE " + KEY_NAME + " = '" + name + "'";
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return data;
}
//---retrieves a particular record--- THIS WILL NOT WORK - NO SUCH TABLE
/* public Cursor getRecord()
{String query1 ="SELECT * FROM" + KEY_TITLE;
    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(query1,null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}*/

// Retrieve a row (single) according to id
public Cursor getRecordById(long id) {
    return DBHelper.getWritableDatabase().query(
            DATABASE_TABLE,
            null,
            KEY_ROWID + "=?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},
            null,null,null
    );
}


//---updates a record---
/* public boolean updateRecord(long rowId, String name, String amount, String duedate)
{
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    args.put(KEY_AMOUNT, amount);
    args.put(KEY_DUEDATE, duedate);
    String whereclause = KEY_ROWID + "=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(rowId)};
    // Will return NULL POINTER EXCEPTION as db isn't set
    //return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    // Replaces commented out line
    return DBHelper.getWritableDatabase().update(DATABASE_TABLE,
            args,
            whereclause,
            whereargs
    ) > 0;
}*/
}
```

Here is my Bills.java (MainActivity)

Problem: Bills.java has the list view that shows the intent whenever the item in list view is clicked, but it does not put the amount and date or update the record. Instead it saves another record.

Solution: I want to retrieve it and display all (name ,amount,duedate) and instead of saving another record it should update it.

```
package com.example.dhruv.bill;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class bills extends AppCompatActivity {
DBAdapter dbAdapter;
ListView mrecycleview;
private static final String TAG ="assignments";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bills);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mrecycleview =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.mRecycleView);
    dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(this);
    // mlistview();
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab1);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Editbills.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    mlistview();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_bills, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
private void mlistview(){
    Log.d(TAG,"mlistview:Display data in listview");
    Cursor mCursor = dbAdapter.getAllRecords();
    ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();
    while (mCursor.moveToNext()){
        listData.add(mCursor.getString(1));
    }
    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listData);
    mrecycleview.setAdapter(adapter);
    mrecycleview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String name = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: You Clicked on " + name);
            Cursor data = dbAdapter.getItemID(name); //get the id associated with that name
            int itemID = -1;
            while(data.moveToNext()){
                itemID = data.getInt(0);
            }
            if(itemID > -1){
                Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: The ID is: " + itemID);
                Intent editScreenIntent = new Intent(bills.this, Editbills.class);
                editScreenIntent.putExtra("id",itemID);
                editScreenIntent.putExtra("name",name);
                startActivity(editScreenIntent);

            }
            else{

            }
        }
    });


}
}
```

here is my editbills.java code

```
package com.example.dhruv.bill;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Editbills extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button;
private static final String Tag= "assignments";
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
private String selectedName;
private int selectedID;
DBAdapter dbAdapter;
private EditText editText,editText2,editText3;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_editbills);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    editText =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    editText3 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    //get the intent extra from the ListDataActivity
    Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();

    //now get the itemID we passed as an extra
    selectedID = receivedIntent.getIntExtra("id",-1); //NOTE: -1 is just the default value

    //now get the name we passed as an extra
    selectedName = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("name");

    //set the text to show the current selected name
    editText.setText(selectedName);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("test", "adding");
            db.open();
            long id = db.insertRecord(editText.getText().toString(), editText2.getText().toString(), editText3.getText().toString());
            db.close();
            Toast.makeText(Editbills.this," Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent q = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),bills.class);
            startActivity(q);

        }
    });
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_bills, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_Delete) {
        db.deleteName(selectedID,selectedName);
        editText.setText("");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent p = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),bills.class);
        startActivity(p);
        return true;

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of 
`DBHelper.getWritableDatabase().insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);`
in insertRecord function of DBHelper, it should be
`DBHelper.getWritableDatabase().update("markers", valores, where, whereArgs);`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50162920/cannot-convert-java-lang-string-into-json-object @Mashal_Rashid please help