# Cannot convert java.lang.string into json object

Tags: android, json, authentication, android-volley

This project is about login where i am trying to login and getting this error.Cannot convert json obj to java.lang . String
what should i do to resolve this error? 
i am getting an error in json object even when i was passing a string value now i change the string value to exact same value where i was getting an error . 
I have tried many things to resolve it by making a string object and then passing it instead of response
But it then showed an error cannot expect a literal value ay character 1. 
This is the PATH of the DB_FUNCTIONS.PHP that it is a string value.

```
/home/awesogp3/public_html/android_login_api/include/DB_Functions.php"
```

here is my DB_FUNCTIONS.PHP

```
<?php

class DB_Functions {

private $conn;

// constructor
function __construct() {
    require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
    // connecting to database
    $db = new Db_Connect();
    $this->conn = $db->connect();
}

// destructor
function __destruct() {

}

/**
 * Storing new user
 * returns user details
 */
public function storeUser($name, $email, $password) {
    $uuid = uniqid('', true);
    $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
    $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $uuid, $name, $email, $encrypted_password, $salt);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();

        return $user;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Get user by email and password
 */
public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();

        // verifying user password
        $salt = $user['salt'];
        $encrypted_password = $user['encrypted_password'];
        $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);
        // check for password equality
        if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
            // user authentication details are correct
            return $user;
        }
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}

/**
 * Check user is existed or not
 */
public function isUserExisted($email) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT email from users WHERE email = ?");

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->store_result();

    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        // user existed 
        $stmt->close();
        return true;
    } else {
        // user not existed
        $stmt->close();
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Encrypting password
 * @param password
 * returns salt and encrypted password
 */
public function hashSSHA($password) {

    $salt = sha1(rand());
    $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
    $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
    $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
    return $hash;
}

/**
 * Decrypting password
 * @param salt, password
 * returns hash string
 */
public function checkhashSSHA($salt, $password) {

    $hash = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);

    return $hash;
}

}

?>
```

Here is my LoginActivity.java where i am trying to login and getting this error.

```
package com.example.dhruv.bill;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.dhruv.bill.R;
import com.example.dhruv.bill.AppConfig;
import com.example.dhruv.bill.AppController;
import com.example.dhruv.bill.SQLiteHandler; 
import com.example.dhruv.bill.SessionManager;
import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private Button btnLogin;
private Button btnLinkToRegister;
private EditText inputEmail;
private EditText inputPassword;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private SessionManager session;
private SQLiteHandler db;
public static final String ID_INTENTEXT = SQLiteHandler.KEY_NAME + "_INTENTEXTRA";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    allow_volley av = new allow_volley();
    av.allow();
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);

    // Progress dialog
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);

    // SQLite database handler
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());


    // Session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    // Check if user is already logged in or not
    if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
        // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    // Login button Click Event
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();
            Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + email);
            Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + password);
            // Check for empty data in the form
            if (!email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                // login user
                checkLogin(email, password);
            } else {
                // Prompt user to enter credentials
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter the credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        }

    });

    // Link to Register Screen
    btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });

}

/**
 * function to verify login details in mysql db
 * */
private void checkLogin(final String email, final String password) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request

    String tag_string_req = "req_login";

    pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                // Check for error node in json
                if (!error) {
                    // user successfully logged in
                    // Create login session
                    session.setLogin(true);
                    // Now store the user in SQLite
                    String uid = jObj.getString("uid");
                    JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                    String name = user.getString("name");
                    String email = user.getString("email");
                    String created_at = user
                            .getString("created_at");

                    // Inserting row in users table
                    db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at);

                    // Launch main activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                    finish();
                } else {
                    // Error in login. Get the error message
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);
            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + email);
    Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + password);
}

private void showDialog() {
    if (!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}

private void hideDialog() {
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}
}
```

This is the log cat

**Notice**:  Use of undefined constant home - assumed 'home' in **/home/awesogp3/public_html/android_login_api/include/DB_Functions.php** on line **2**
    
    **Notice**:  Use of undefined constant public_html - assumed 'public_html' in **/home/awesogp3/public_html/android_login_api/include/DB_Functions.php** on line **2**
    
    **Warning**:  Division by zero in **/home/awesogp3/public_html/android_login_api/include/DB_Functions.php** on line **2**
    
    **Notice**:  Use of undefined constant awesogp3 - assumed 'awesogp3' in **/home/awesogp3/public_html/android_login_api/include/DB_Functions.php** on line **2**
    
    **Warning**:  Division by zero in **/home/awesogp3/public_html/android_login_api/include/DB_Functions.php** on line **2**
    
    **Notice**:  Use of undefined constant android_login_api - assumed 'android_login_api' in **/home/awesogp3/public_html/android_login_api/include/DB_Functions.php** on line **2**
    
    **Warning**:  Division by zero in **/home/awesogp3/public_html/android_login_api/include/DB_Functions.php** on line **2**
    false
    **Fatal error**:  Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in **/home/awesogp3/public_html/android_login_api/include/DB_Functions.php** on line **60**

Comment: You're passing in the path of your PHP file into the `JSONObject` constructor, but it's expecting an actual JSON string. Where is the JSON stored that you actually want to parse? That's what you should be passing into the constructor.

Comment: What changes I should make in the code to make it run ?

Comment: Shall i make a constructor ? For JSON object @pushasha